# Prestashop localization fail to Import a localization pack

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Prestashop (1.6.1.10) localization fail to Import a localization pack (Israel)

I get

```
[PrestaShopException]

Property Currency->decimals is not valid
at line 909 in file classes/ObjectModel.php

904.             }
905. 
906.             $message = $this->validateField($field, $this->$field);
907.             if ($message !== true) {
908.                 if ($die) {
909.                     throw new PrestaShopException($message);
910.                 }
911.                 return $error_return ? $message : false;
912.             }
913.         }
914. 
ObjectModelCore->validateFields - [line 299 - classes/LocalizationPack.php]
LocalizationPackCore->_installCurrencies - [line 97 - classes/LocalizationPack.php] - [1 Arguments]
LocalizationPackCore->loadLocalisationPack - [line 203 - controllers/admin/AdminLocalizationController.php] - [4 Arguments]
AdminLocalizationControllerCore->postProcess - [line 178 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 58 - admin/index.p
```

This is used to work in the passed, I think something is broken in the language page

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I by-pass the issue:

In the  IMPORT A LOCALIZATION PACK form, uncheck Currency.

Import the pack, and create the currency manually.